# Why do i have to service my gearless Honda Activa every 2 weeks

Tags: honda, battery, suspension, fuel-consumption

I currently own a [Honda Activa](http://www.motorbikes.be/en/Honda_Activa_2005.aspx) which is of a 2007 make. After three years during a heavy traffic jam the conveyer belt got heated up and burnt due to continuous acceleration and braking. I got it serviced and from then onwards the Vehicle has to be serviced after every 2-3 weeks. This servicing is getting heavy on my time(if I give them in the morning then they will take two days to get it serviced completely) and pocket(charges for shock absorbers and the brake etc. make the bill to around 1,500-2,000 INR/- ).

Every time I go and complain about the shock absorbers which are not giving any comfort given the pathetic roads present. The  battery goes down after 2 weeks and gives the burden on the Head lights getting dim. The list goes on and the biggest problem is availability of spares for older model due to which it sometimes takes even three days.

Can you suggest me what are the exact problems that I need to specify to get it serviced perfectly.(Before giving it for service I need to specify what exactly the problem I am facing if I miss out even one single problem then I have to wait another 7 days to get it serviced)

Do you suggest me to continue with the servicing or go in for a new model or take another gearless from another company like [Suzuki access 125](http://www.suzukimotorcycle.co.in/access125_detailsprice.aspx), hero maestro

Comment: You may want to get your hands dirty/greasy if you want to save money on services. Besides, OE spares are overpriced too; just another way of making profit.

Answer (score 3):

You don't want them to service it "perfectly"; it'd be prohibitively expensive, much more expensive than the scooter's replacement value. Sure, you'd have a nearly essentially brand-new scooter... but it'd still have some of the weaknesses of age and torture. Metal does fatigue over time, especially if it's subjected to rough use (you mentioned poor road conditions).

For YOUR purposes, it may be more cost-effective to replace the scooter than to chase repairs on this one; you don't sound like the sort of person who's comfortable with wrenches in both hands and a scredriver in their back pocket.

As to brand... that's a very personal choice. Is that scooter listed in Consumer Reports? CR is an excellent way to predict, with some degree of confidence, the reliability and repairability of all sorts of equipment - scooters included.

What are other people around you riding? Notice especially things that people are riding that're OLD. That's often a decent indicator of general reliability.

Comment: Around me they are going in for diff versions of the model and as per this [site](http://visual.ly/top-7-gearless-scooters-india) the 2013 model is used most

Comment: That's a pretty strong indication that your next scooter should probably be something like the 2013 model of that same scooter. If nothing else, there should be plenty of places that fix them just because there are so many of them.

Comment: I am open to new model's but it's just that Sale of Honda Scooters are more when compared to the other models as given in the site and there is no availability of some parts like the speedometer display bulbs etc. because I have given for servicing since two months and every time the servicemen say they do not have parts and don't know when the parts for 2007 model will arrive because now there are models of 2013,2009 presently in the markets.